# Complex Weighted Average in R by group by date

Tags: r

I have a data set of multiple products (3 in the example, 200 in real) and each product has a discount in percentage and belongs to a location on a specific day. The discount can change as well as the location and the value of the goods.

```
Date        Item    Discount    Value   Location
12/16/2019  AAA     4%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAA     5%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAA     6%          11500   BP2
12/16/2019  AAC     3%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAC     4%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAC     12%         13000   BP3
12/16/2019  BBC     12%         13500   BP3
12/17/2019  BBC     3%          11000   BP2
12/16/2019  BBC     1%          9000    BP1
```

**I am looking to calculate the weighted average discount per location per date.**

For example on `12/16/2019`, `W.BP1` (weighted average discount in `BP1`) is: `2.72%`
(`Value of each item in PB1 divided by sum of the values, multiplied by the respective discount, then summed up`).

The result would look like this:

```
Date        Location    Weighted.Discount
12/16/2019  BP1         2.72%
12/16/2019  …           …
12/16/2019  …           …
```

I can do it in excel for a few rows and locations, but need to find an R way of doing.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` is a good way to do and visualize this:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(Discount = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", Discount))/100) %>%
  group_by(Date, Location) %>%
  summarize(Weighted.Discount = sum(Discount * Value/sum(Value))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   Date       Location Weighted.Discount
#   <chr>      <chr>                <dbl>
# 1 12/16/2019 BP1                 0.0272
# 2 12/16/2019 BP2                 0.06  
# 3 12/16/2019 BP3                 0.12  
# 4 12/17/2019 BP1                 0.045 
# 5 12/17/2019 BP2                 0.03
```

Both `Date` and `Discount` are in a "categorical" mode. If you intend to use them analytically (order by date, calculate differences, multiply values, etc), then you need to convert them into "proper" R objects. I've converted `Discount` above, but you can convert `Date` with something like

```r
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
```

(within the rest of the pipeline).

Also, I assumed a US standard for "dot" in the number to indicate fractional component using the regular expression `[0-9.]`; if your locale uses commas, for instance, you can change that to `[0-9,]`.

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Date        Item    Discount    Value   Location
12/16/2019  AAA     4%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAA     5%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAA     6%          11500   BP2
12/16/2019  AAC     3%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAC     4%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAC     12%         13000   BP3
12/16/2019  BBC     12%         13500   BP3
12/17/2019  BBC     3%          11000   BP2
12/16/2019  BBC     1%          9000    BP1")
```

Comment: So much nicer than the loops I was starting to build. looks like dplyr is THE package?

Comment: Many will argue that it can make some types of data-munging pipelines a little easier to visualize (using the clear verbs) and/or create with clarity. I'm a little faster to demonstrate something in `dplyr` than `data.table` or even base R, though I don't think it's the panacea of R-goodness. \*shrug\*

Comment: (Said differently: many will argue that `data.table` is superior in most if not all ways. I don't fully agree, but I find its memory/speed improvements very useful for my larger-data work, and so far it is the only robust way for doing in-memory inequity joins.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a `data.table` method:

```
data.table(data.table)


dt[, Discount := as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", 
    Discount))/100][, .(Weighted.Discount = sum(Discount * Value/sum(Value))), 
    by = .(Date, Location)]

#          Date Location Weighted.Discount
# 1: 12/16/2019      BP1          2.764138
# 2: 12/16/2019      BP2          6.040000
# 3: 12/16/2019      BP3          0.000012
# 4: 12/17/2019      BP1          4.540000
# 5: 12/17/2019      BP2          3.040000
```

---

Data:

```
dt <- fread("
Date        Item    Discount    Value   Location
12/16/2019  AAA     4%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAA     5%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAA     6%          11500   BP2
12/16/2019  AAC     3%          10000   BP1
12/17/2019  AAC     4%          11000   BP1
12/16/2019  AAC     12%         13000   BP3
12/16/2019  BBC     12%         13500   BP3
12/17/2019  BBC     3%          11000   BP2
12/16/2019  BBC     1%          9000    BP1")
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you went with `\`:=\` (...)` vice just `Discount := (...)`? I find the former method hand when I have multiple assignments (though there are other ways to do that, too).